# Relative continuity of a function

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I've come across the following generalization of continuity in a rather surprising place.

Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ be functions. Say $f$ is continuous relative to $g$ at $x\in X$ if for every open neighborhood $U$ of $f(x)$ there is a neighorhood $V$ of $x$ such that $g(f(V))\subseteq g(U)$. Say $f$ is continuous relative to $g$ if it is continuous relative to $g$ at every point in $x$.

Of course, $f$ is continuous relative to $id_Y$ iff $f$ is continuous and every function is continuous relative to a constant function.

Does this property have a more common name? Does it appear naturally anywhere else?